# Ruby/Rails - force subclasses to override specific methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm wondering if there is a way to force a subclass to override a method from its parent method in either Ruby or Rails (in Java you would do this with an [abstract class/method](https://www.javatpoint.com/abstract-class-in-java)).

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class Pet
end

class Dog < Pet
  def collar_color
    "red"
  end
end

class Cat < Pet
end

dog = Dog.new
dog.collar_color
==> red

cat = Cat.new
cat.collar_color
==> NoMethodError
```

In this example I would never instantiate a Pet object, but it exists to serve as a way to collect common methods to common classes. But let's say I want to ensure that all subclasses of Pet override the `collar_color` method. Is there a way to do that? Could I achieve it through testing in some way? Assume I don't want a default defined in the parent class.

My real-life use case is a collection of classes that all have polymorphic ownership of another class. If I have a display page of the owned class, then one of the owner classes not having a method could leave me with a `NoMethodError` problem.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to enforce this.

I can guarantee you, whatever idea you can come up with, it will break in some way.

First off: doing this statically is out of the question. Determining whether a method is overridden or not is known to be equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

So, you have to do it dynamically. But even that is going to be problematic.

For example: you could implement the `inherited` hook and check whether every class that inherits from `Pet` implements the method. But, that will prevent someone from inheriting their own abstract class. (Also, there is no guarantee *when* the `inherited` hook will run – it could run when the class is opened, i.e. before the methods are defined.)

Also, even if you can check that the method exists at the point where a class inherits `Pet`, the method can still be removed again later, so you don't get any guarantees. And, of course, they can just provide a dummy method, in order to get around your protection.

You *could* create default implementations of the methods that just `raise` an `Exception`, but there is no need to do that: if you *don't* create a default implementation, that will already `raise` a `NoMethodError` exception anyway. (If you *do* go down this route, *do not* use [`NotImplementedError`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/NotImplementedError.html). Instead, use a custom exception that inherits from [`RuntimeError`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/RuntimeError.html).)

There are examples of this in the core library: for example, the `Enumerable` mixin depends on an abstract method `each` that must be implemented by subclasses. And the way this is handled is by simply [documenting](https://ruby-doc.org/3.1.3/Enumerable.html#module-Enumerable-label-Usage) that fact:

> ## Usage
>
> To use module Enumerable in a collection class:
>
> - Include it:
>
>   ```ruby
>   include Enumerable
>   ```
> - Implement method `#each` which must yield successive elements of the collection. The method will be called by almost any Enumerable method.

That is actually the way any type-related issues have been dealt with in Ruby since the beginning. Since Ruby does not have types, typing only happens in the programmer's head and type information is only written down in documentation.

There always were *informal* third-party type annotation languages that were used by various IDEs. More recently, two type annotation languages have been introduced: RBI, a third-party type annotation language used by the Sorbet type checker, and [RBS](https://github.com/ruby/rbs), a type annotation language that is part of Ruby proper.

As far as I know, RBS has no way of expressing abstract methods, but [RBI does](https://sorbet.org/docs/abstract):

```ruby
class Pet
  extend T::Sig
  extend T::Helpers
  interface!

  sig {abstract.returns(String)}
  def collar_color; end
end
```

This will give you a type error if there is object instantiated from a subclass that does not at some point in the inheritance chain define the method. But, of course, *only* if the user of the code actually type-checks the code using a type-checker like [Sorbet](https://sorbet.org/). If the user of the code does not type-check it, they will not get a type error.

Comment: The `inherited` hook won't help much – it runs the moment you open the class body, i.e. before any method is defined.

Comment: You can use the `inherited` hook to register the class in a list of classes to be checked at some later point, though. But hey, I *did* write that it would be problematic and break :-D

Comment: @Stefan: Actually, I think it's even worse. If I remember some of the discussions correctly, *there is no guarantee*. So, it *could* run at the beginning, but it *could* also run at the end, or even halfway through. (Currently, all implementors run it at the beginning, but that is an implementation detail, not part of the [contract](https://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Class:inherited). I believe it would be perfectly legal to run it in parallel on a different thread.)

Comment: That's right, and even `ruby/spec` doesn't test the point of invocation. Besides, it would be perfectly fine to reopen the class to add the missing methods later on. The existence of a subclass (or object in general) doesn't imply that it is "complete" or won't change anymore.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Love your answer. What are your thoughts about a set of model tests they can each have that are essentially `assert_respond_to Object, collar_color`?

Answer (score 3):

Ruby has relatively few keywords but it provides the basic building blocks to implement something that vaguely resembles abstract classes or methods.

In its simplest form you just raise an error in the parent "abstract" method:

```
class AbstractMethodError < StandardError
  def initialize(klass, m)
    super("Expected #{klass} to implement #{m}")
  end
end

class Pet
  def collar_color
    raise AbstractMethodError.new(self.class, __method__)
  end
end

class Cat < Pet
  
end

Cat.new.collar_color # Expected Cat to implement collar_color (AbstractMethodError)
```

`__method__` is a magic variable that contains the name of the current method.

You can make this a bit more elegant by creating a class method that defines the "abstract method":

```
module Abstractions
  def abstract_method(name)
    define_method(name) do
      raise AbstractMethodError.new(self.class, __method__)
    end
  end
end

class Pet
  extend Abstractions
  abstract_method :collar_color
end
```

However Ruby is a dynamic langauge and you don't have a compile time check so this will only give a slightly more obvious error message when the method  is called. It doesn't actually give any guarentees that subclasses implement the method.

That is down to testing or using type checkers like Sorbet or RBS. In general it might be helpful when learning to forget everything you think you know about Object Oriented Programming and learn the Ruby way. It has a very different design philophy compared to Java - instead of abstract methods and interfaces you use duck typing to see if the object responds to that method.

Comment: This is the usual approach. However, the error would only be raised if the method is actually called, just like the `NoMethodError` the OP already gets.

Comment: @Stefan that's were tests come in. You could I guess create a class instance variable in the parent that contains the names of all the "abstract" methods and then loop through the decendendants to see if they have implemented all those methods but it feels so un-Rubyeske and silly to even contemplate it.

Comment: I normally go with the built-in `NotImplementedError`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: `NotImplementedError` is for platform-specific code that cannot be supported on the current platform, such as, for example, writing to the filesystem in code running in a browser or `fork`ing on Windows. Also, `NotImplementedError` does not inherit from `StandardError`, so it will not be caught by a default `rescue` block. There is a current Feature Request to widen its scope, though: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18915 But widening the scope will not change the inheritance chain, it's purely a documentation change.

Answer (score 1):

Just define the default method implementation in the abstract class by raising Not implemented error or something. By doing that you also clarifies in your class design that when others / you want to inherit the `Pet` class they need to override `collar_color` method. Clarity is a good think and there is no benefit in not defining a default method in the abstract class.

Or if you want to achieve that by testing you can create a test case for `Pet` class that check if its descendants is defining their own `collar_color` method or not. I think Rails / Ruby 3.1 have `.descendants` methods defined or you can just google them.

```html
# Pet_spec.rb 
describe "descendants must implement collar_color" do
  it "should not throw error" do
    descendants = Pet.descendants
    descendants.each do |descendant|
      expect { descendant.new.collar_color }.to.not raise_error
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do *not* `raise` `NotImplementedError`. `NotImplementedError` is for *platform-specific code that cannot be supported on the current platform*, such as, for example, writing to the filesystem in Opal or `fork`ing on Windows. Also, `NotImplementedError` does not inherit from `StandardError`, so it will not be caught by a default `rescue` block.